WebSraping in python using Books to Scrape website
I have a question about my code, because it does not work. Visual Studio shows AttributeError on category variable - Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 11, in 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
And I cannot figure it out, where is the problem. I am stuck, So if somebody know where I am making mistake I would be glad. Here is the code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

books_data = []
for page_num in range(1,51):
    url = f'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{page_num}.html'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    books = soup.find_all('h3')

    for book in books:
        book_url = book.find('a')['href']
        book_response = requests.get(url + book_url)
        book_soup = BeautifulSoup(book_response.content, 'html.parser')
        
        title = book_soup.find('h1').text
        category = book_soup.find('ul', class_ = 'breadcrumb').find_all('a')[2].text.strip()
        rating = book_soup.find('p', class_ = 'star-rating')['class'][1]
        price = book_soup.find('p', class_ = 'price_color').text.strip()
        availibility = book_soup.find('p', class_ = 'availibility').text.strip()

        books_data = ([title, category, rating, price, availibility])
print(books_data)


It looks like you're trying to crawl the site, which means that you want to extract links and follow those.
The issue that you're running into is because of how you construct these links in the following line:
book_response = requests.get(url + book_url)

Try to add a breakpoint() in the line below this one and inspect what the variables url and book_url hold:
>>> url
'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'
>>> book_url
'a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html'

This means that constructing the URL that you then try to scrape gives:
'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.htmla-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html'
That's not a valid URL and therefore your request returns a <Response [404]>. Requests can't find that page (because it doesn't exist). You'll have to construct the URL differently to get to a valid page, e.g.:
>>> url.rsplit('/', 1)[0] + "/" + book_url
'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html'

You can then scrape the book detail page with this valid URL and keep going.

Note that I'd also suggest to go through your code and remove unnecessary imports etc. to make it cleaner and easier to reason about.
For the code to work, you'll also have to:

Import requests
Fix a typo in availability
Indent your call to print() into the loop body

Good luck, have fun learning, and hope that helps!
